# ClassDefNotFoundException

Tags: java

What is ClassDefNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError and explain differences between these two?

Comment: homework or interview question?

Comment: have you tried searching? what did you find?

Comment: Sorry, but this is pretty clear from the Javadoc. The only thing that may require more explaination is the difference between Exception and Error, but I'm sure there are plenty of questions already asking that. @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - it would be a mighty nasty interview question, unless the answer they were after was 'I'd look it up in the Javadoc'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown if the class failed to initialize.

When a class is used for the 1st time, it's being initialized. if that fails for whatever reason, the relevant exception is thrown.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4

When the class is used again, it's known to be corrupt. Initialization won't be attempted again. JVM throws the mysterious `NoClassDefFoundError`. Not really descriptive of the problem, could be quite confusing for diagnosis. It would be better if something like `ClassInitFailedError` is thrown.

When you see a `NoClassDefFoundError`, you should search the log backwards, find the root cause why the class failed to initialize (hopefully it's logged)

---

There is no ClassDefNotFoundException  in standard Java lib, so I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Yeah, it's ClassNotFoundException. As it's checked anyone who's done anything with the reflection libraries should be all too familiar with it. NoClassDefFoundError comes up when you've compiled against a class that the runtime can't find. It appears most often when the classpath in your build doesn't match the classpath for your runtime, and also when you're doing stuff like mocking and DI I think.

Comment: failure to resolve other classes could be one of the causes that initialization process failed. but in general many things can go wrong. in my own practice, the majority cases are that static initializers have programming errors and end abruptly.

Answer (score 2):

`ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when the class cannot be found in the classpath. `NoClassDefFoundError` happens when class cannot be instantiated by `new` because the jvm failed to initialize the class. It could be the constructor threw exceptions, or static block threw up, or version mismatch.

Answer (score -2):

Core Java - What is ClassDefNotFoundException and ...

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/47825

Comment: Apparently you are googling for Selva and spitting out the first result here..this will result in more trivial questions being asked here in this forum...